# Compare date values between 3 columns in SQL Server and pull asset information in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with three date columns and some asset information.

- ASSET (APPR_DATE_1, APPR_DATE_2, APPR_DATE_3, ID, NAME, ADDRESS,...)

Sample data:

```
'1-1-2010','1-1-2012','1-1-2015',1,'Peter','USA'....
'1-1-2015','1-10-2014','1-19-2013',2,1,'John','USA'....
'1-1-2008','1-25-2010','4-29-2011',3,'Edward','UK'....
'1-25-2012','10-25-2011','9-11-2013',4,'Nancy','Kenya'....
```

Desired result:

```
'1-1-2010','1-1-2012','1-1-2015',1,'Peter','USA'....
'1-1-2008','1-25-2010','4-29-2011',3,'Edward','UK'....
'1-25-2012','10-25-2011','9-11-2013',4,'Nancy','Kenya'....
```

If you see the result set, it contains 1 row less than sample data. The result set contains only those rows where the difference between most recent and second recent date is greater than 365 OR difference between second recent date and oldest date is greater than 365

They have random dates. For each row, I need to find the recent, second recent and oldest date and once I get that, I need to compare -

1. List out the assets information where Difference between recent date and second recent date is greater than 1 year.
2. List out the assets information where Difference between second recent date and oldest date is greater than 1 year.
3. Point 2 should NOT include the assets which are already included in point 1

Col `ID` is unique. Is this possible in SQL?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But in order for us to help you, help us understand your question by providing sample data and expected result.

Comment: You need to start with something. So start with `SELECT *  FROM ASSET`. Next try `SELECT *, DATEDIFF(y,APPR_DATE_1, APPR_DATE_2) As Diff1 FROM ASSET`. Do you have any idea how to build it up from that? It's just a bunch of boolean logic based around the results of `DATEDIFF`. The tedious part is that if the three dates are in random order, you need to try every combination.

Comment: Or you could start with some logic to order the dates consistently and build on that: `SELECT CASE WHEN APPR_DATE_1 > APPR_DATE_2 AND APPR_DATE_1 > APPR_DATE_3 THEN APPR_DATE_1 WHEN APPR_DATE_2 > APPR_DATE_1 AND APPR_DATE_2 > APPR_DATE_3 THEN APPR_DATE_2 ELSE APPR_DATE_3 END D1 FROM ASSET`

Comment: @FelixPamittan - Hey, I have added sample data. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @FelixPamittan - Hey sorry, I updated my result. If you see the result set, it contains 1 row less than sample data. The result set contains only those rows where the difference between most recent and second recent date is greater than 365 OR difference between second recent date and oldest date is greater than 365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CASE` expressions to determine the recent, second, and oldest date. Put them in a `CTE` and use the column names in the `WHERE` clause

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
        RecentDate =
            CASE
                WHEN APPR_DATE_1 >= APPR_DATE_2 AND APPR_DATE_1 >= APPR_DATE_3 THEN APPR_DATE_1
                WHEN APPR_DATE_2 >= APPR_DATE_3 AND APPR_DATE_2 >= APPR_DATE_1 THEN APPR_DATE_2
                WHEN APPR_DATE_3 >= APPR_DATE_2 AND APPR_DATE_3 >= APPR_DATE_1 THEN APPR_DATE_3
            END,
        SecondDate =
            CASE
                WHEN APPR_DATE_1 BETWEEN APPR_DATE_2 AND APPR_DATE_3 OR APPR_DATE_1 BETWEEN APPR_DATE_3 AND APPR_DATE_2 THEN APPR_DATE_1
                WHEN APPR_DATE_2 BETWEEN APPR_DATE_1 AND APPR_DATE_3 OR APPR_DATE_1 BETWEEN APPR_DATE_3 AND APPR_DATE_1 THEN APPR_DATE_2
                WHEN APPR_DATE_3 BETWEEN APPR_DATE_1 AND APPR_DATE_2 OR APPR_DATE_1 BETWEEN APPR_DATE_2 AND APPR_DATE_1 THEN APPR_DATE_3
            END,
        OldestDate =
            CASE
                WHEN APPR_DATE_1 <= APPR_DATE_2 AND APPR_DATE_1 <= APPR_DATE_3 THEN APPR_DATE_1
                WHEN APPR_DATE_2 <= APPR_DATE_3 AND APPR_DATE_2 <= APPR_DATE_1 THEN APPR_DATE_2
                WHEN APPR_DATE_3 <= APPR_DATE_2 AND APPR_DATE_3 <= APPR_DATE_1 THEN APPR_DATE_3             
            END
    FROM #ASSET
)
SELECT
    APPR_DATE_1, APPR_DATE_2, APPR_DATE_3, ID, NAME, ADDRESS 
FROM CTE
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(DAY, SecondDate, RecentDate) > 365
    OR DATEDIFF(DAY, OldestDate, SecondDate) > 365
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/486582)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

the query seems busy, but it should work for you.

```
  select * from 
  (
  --then pivot it back to get the columns in order
  select id, 
  [1] as APPR_DATE_1
  ,[2] as APPR_DATE_2
  ,[3] as APPR_DATE_3
  from(
  select id , APPR_DATE ,row_number() over (partition by id order by APPR_DATE asc) as rowid
  from (

  --unpivot first 
  select id , APPR_DATE_1 ,APPR_DATE_2,APPR_DATE_3 from #table
  ) as cp
  unpivot
  (
  APPR_DATE for APPR_DATES in (APPR_DATE_1 ,APPR_DATE_2,APPR_DATE_3)
  ) as up

  ) as x
  pivot
  (
  max(APPR_DATE)
  for 
  rowid in ([1],[2],[3])
  )
  as pv

  )xx
  where  datediff("dd",APPR_DATE_1,APPR_DATE_2)/365 <> 0 or 
  datediff("dd",APPR_DATE_2,APPR_DATE_3)/365 <> 0
```