# replace main date by higher date if, sql,mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `post` where there is this dates arrangement:

**table posts**

```
id_post    |   post      |      date_a   |  date_b      |  date_main
1               hi1           00:01:00      00:02:00        00:00:01    
2               hi2                                         00:00:02    
3               hi3                         00:05:00        00:00:03    
4               hi4           00:08:00      00:05:00        00:00:04    
5               hi4           00:09:00                      00:00:05
```

I need to replace the `date` by the higher date & default `date_main`

**Expected output**

```
id_post  |    post          |  date
1               hi1           00:02:00  
2               hi2           00:00:02  
3               hi3           00:05:00  
4               hi4           00:08:00
5               hi4           00:09:00
```

**sql attempt**

```
SELECT id_post,post,IF(date_a IS NOT NULL, date_a,date_main) as date
FROM posts
WHERE 1
```

I tried using `if()` but it works only when I have date_a & date_main, or date_b and date_main, but it doesnt work when I try to work with all three dates,

**How do I get the expected output?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work if you are using NULL values in the database.  It assumes date_main is always the lowest number.

```
SELECT id_post, GREATEST(COALESCE(date_a,0),COALESCE(date_b,0), COALESCE(date_main,0) as dt1 FROM `posts`
```

Comment: awesome approach. Ill try that out. +1

Comment: I guess this would be enough `GREATEST(date_a,date_b, date_main)`

Comment: As long as date_main is always the lowest number, you're good.  Otherwise, if date_a or date_b exists and date_main is the highest, date_main will get returned.

Comment: I updated my answer assuming date_main is always the lowest.

Comment: fors some reason it doesnt work in my code, does `greatest()` works for timestamp dates? returns Nulls

Comment: I feel silly.  I forgot to use COALESCE to account for the null values.  What comes of not testing in mysql.  Wrap the fields as such: COALESCE(date_a,0)

Comment: @KarenVicknair yes `coalesce()` was the function I was looking for to make the code run properly. It works pretty good now. thank you for your answer. marked!

Answer (score 2):

Use case when for comparison

```
SELECT
  id_post,
  post,
  case when date_a > date_main
    then date_a
  else date_main end as date
FROM posts
WHERE 1
```

Comment: ok, thank you good approach. but what about `date_b` in your code? nulls?

Comment: then you can compare 3 dates together

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37265336/compare-date-values-between-3-columns-in-sql-server-and-pull-asset-information-i

Comment: do you have any approach, because having to compare three values, bearing in mind `date_a` and `date_b` could be NULL, it adds up a lot of when cases

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0ae69778-4adb-4862-aff9-27d634340e90/compare-the-3-columns-and-pick-up-the-latest-date?forum=transactsql

Comment: you can check those links where you can find how to compare 3dates value

Answer (score 1):

you can use CASE in sql

example:

```
case 
when date_a is not null then date_a
when date_b is not null then date_b
else date_main
end as datee
```